# IOS: UIImageView border white with radius display a strange dark line in 4 corners

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiimageview

I set the border white and radius for my `ImageView`. But in 4 corner of the `ImageView`, some dark line appear.
Here is the code I set the color for my `ImageView`

```
self.image.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
self.image.layer.borderWidth = 3;
self.image.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
self.image.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

This is a small demo project. My storyboard **only contains** the `ImageView`, and I don't set any constraint for my `ImageView`.

I don't know why this happened, it have tested on simulator and real device but it give a same error

Here is demo project: (it's very simple) https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_poNaia6t8kT0JLSFJleGxEcmc/view?usp=sharing

**Update**
Some people give a solution is change the color of border color from `whiteColor` to `clearColor`. Of course it will make 4 lines disappear. But if I using `clearColor`, I don't need to add border to my `ImageView`.
I need border white for some reason

[image]

Comment: are you added the self.image to any subview

Comment: no, I just drag it to my mainStoryboard

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I have add a demo project, if you don't mind, can you check it

Comment: actually your image size is too big

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18515698/1949494

Comment: hi I give answer please check and if it work for you then please up vote my answer

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik , did you change my image to smaller size image and it's work

Comment: no I m get the same output

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thank you for your time. I will try to figure out the problem because actually it need a whiteColor border not clearColor border

Comment: The issue is older and it is not going to work. Why don't you use a `CAShapeLayer`?

Comment: @Jelly I have checked your suggest link, but it don't mention to border color, it just about set border radius. I'm new in iOS, i don't know about `CAShapeLayer`. if you don't mind can you check my demo project. it very light and simple

Comment: @PhanVănLinh -- I got the output

Comment: @Phan Văn Linh I put an answer with the code that does that. Just paste it in your sample project instead of the existing one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Updated code**

I tried your code actually your image size is big initially I resized the image based on original Image size

```
UIImage *myIcon = [self imageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.jpg"] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(400, 400)];
self.image.image = myIcon;
```

sometimes corner radius does not work properly so I used `UIBezierPath` for this concept

```
 UIBezierPath *maskPath;
maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.image.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight | UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
self.image.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

for border color and width use this

**swift 3**

```
let maskPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: imageView.bounds, byRoundingCorners: ([.topLeft, .topRight, .bottomLeft, .bottomRight]), cornerRadii: CGSize(width: 10.0, height: 10.0))


    let borderShape = CAShapeLayer()
    borderShape.frame = self.imageView.bounds
    borderShape.path = maskPath.cgPath
    borderShape.strokeColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    borderShape.fillColor = nil
    borderShape.lineWidth = 3
    self.imageView.layer.addSublayer(borderShape)
```

**output**

[image]

**Update**

```
CAShapeLayer*   borderShape = [CAShapeLayer layer];
borderShape.frame = self.image.bounds;
borderShape.path = maskPath.CGPath;
borderShape.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
borderShape.fillColor = nil;
borderShape.lineWidth = 3;
[self.image.layer addSublayer:borderShape];
```

**Swift**

```
var borderShape: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer.layer
borderShape.frame = self.image.bounds
borderShape.path = maskPath.CGPath
borderShape.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
borderShape.fillColor = nil
borderShape.lineWidth = 3
 self.image.layer.addSublayer(borderShape)
```

**Output**

[image]

Code for [**whole project**](https://www.sendspace.com/file/ilb9x6)

Comment: thank you but you forgot my border 3px with `whiteColor`. can you add this to the code. I have add it in my code but it don't display correct

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik super bro

Answer (score 1):

Actually you have to use two layers.

```
self.image.clipsToBounds = YES;
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.image.bounds byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerAllCorners cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(48, 48)];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = self.image.bounds;
maskLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
maskLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;

self.image.layer.mask = maskLayer;

CAShapeLayer*   frameLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
frameLayer.frame = self.image.bounds;
frameLayer.path = maskPath.CGPath;
frameLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor whiteColor].CGColor;
frameLayer.fillColor = nil;
frameLayer.lineWidth = 20;
[self.image.layer addSublayer:frameLayer];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try clip to bounds:

```
self.image.clipToBounds = YES
```

Answer (score 0):

i tried this function written in imageview category:

```
- (void)setBorderWithRounCornersWithColor:(UIColor *)color{

    self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;

    if(color){

        self.layer.borderColor=color.CGColor;
        self.layer.borderWidth=1.0f;
    }

}
```

at time of using:

```
[self.imageView setBorderWithRounCornersWithColor:nil];
```

Comment: it's not working. 4 dark line still visible. if you don't mind, please check my demo project (that I have included in the question)

Answer (score 0):

when you add a border that add in inside the image border line and when you set rounded border that time your round corner has some transparent part so that part will display in corner side
just change the Color of border color

```
image1.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
image1.layer.borderWidth = 3;
image1.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];
image1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;


image2.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
image2.layer.borderWidth = 3;
image2.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
image2.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

[image: Check my image one has a white border color and one is clear color]

Comment: I need a white color for my border, not `clearColor`
if you don't mind, please check my demo project (that I have included in the question)

Answer (score 0):

I check your code you can change this line its work for me

self.image.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];

Comment: if I set the color of border to clearColor, than I don't need to add border to my `ImageView`

Comment: then you have to set border width is 0

Comment: :( sorry for my bad explain, but in my case, it need a border with `whiteColor` not `clearColor`

Answer (score 0):

recently got same issue, but in slightly different context.

Result with ugly black border:

```swift
let image = UIImage(named: "File.png")!
let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 60
let frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: image.size)
let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: frame, cornerRadius: cornerRadius)
let rounded = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size: image.size).image { context in
    path.addClip()
    image.draw(in: frame)
}
```

but if we add `.insetBy(dx: 1, dy: 1)` to `frame` - it will solve the problem.