# Image showing just outside border - iOS/Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, uiimage, border

I'm getting super nitpicky here, because for the most part the border is working here, but the slightest piece of the image still pokes out behind a border I have set. I've tried adjusting the border size and it doesn't help. Is there something wrong with this code? See image below as well for what I'm talking about.

```
func makeItCircle () {
    userImage.layer.masksToBounds = false
    userImage.layer.cornerRadius = CGFloat(roundf(Float(self.userImage.frame.size.width/2.0)))
    userImage.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFill
    userImage.layer.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    userImage.layer.borderWidth = 3
    userImage.clipsToBounds = true
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a known issue with borders. Check my answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36176479/1949494) question if you need a border, otherwise you could just use `clearColor`.

Comment: Interesting. I think I get most of that code, but the one line I'm having trouble translating to Swift is CAShapeLayer*   frameLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];

Comment: `let frameLayer = CAShapeLayer()`

Answer (score 0):

Its a border width,check by giving border width to just 0.5 or 1.0

Comment: That isn't it. I've tried to adjust the border width and the piece of the image still pokes through.