# How can I set UIButton image, which Image is round shape with border

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton, uiimage

How can I set UIButton image, which Image is round shape with border I write related code but image not displaying in proper round shape..
Here is my code..

```
    btnMyProfile.setImage(UIImage(named: "MyDefaultImg.png"), for: .normal)
    btnMyProfile.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    btnMyProfile.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = (btnMyProfile.imageView?.frame.width)! / 2
    btnMyProfile.imageView?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
    btnMyProfile.imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
```

My o/p look like this..
[image]

But I need like this..
[image]

What can I do for achieve my desired output?

Answer (score 5):

set `clipsToBounds = true` for your imageview

```
btnMyProfile.imageView.clipsToBounds = true
```

or use

```
btnMyProfile.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

From the [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/reference/quartzcore/calayer/1410818-cornerradius):

> By default, the corner radius does not apply to the image in the
>   layer’s contents property; it applies only to the background color and
>    border of the layer. However, setting the masksToBounds property to
>   true causes the content to be clipped to the rounded corners.

else another option use [UIBezierPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36174991/ios-uiimageview-border-white-with-radius-display-a-strange-dark-line-in-4-corne/36176242#36176242)

Comment: I change my button size to Square so perfect round is visible but I need to set small image in my button. So how can I do ?

Comment: @NiravS - resize your image and apply your corner radious , see for scale the image https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545955/scale-image-to-smaller-size-in-swift3

Comment: @NiravS - r u get the idea or you need any other support

Comment: @NiravS - how you did it, if my answer is useful accept it

Answer (score 1):

if you want second type of output you should decrease the size of image.( eg 32x32 or 40x40) and  instead of doing
 `btnMyProfile.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = (btnMyProfile.imageView?.frame.width)! / 2` 
you should do

```
 btnMyProfile.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = image.size.width / 2
```

the rest of your code seems OK..

Answer (score 0):

```
    func roundedImageView(imgView: UIImageView, borderWidth: Float, borderColor: UIColor)
{
    imgView.layer.cornerRadius = imgView.frame.size.width / 2
    imgView.clipsToBounds = true
    imgView.layer.borderWidth = CGFloat(borderWidth)
    imgView.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor
}
```

Comment: But I need the big size of button (Rectangle shape) thats why give rounded shape to image view

Answer (score 0):

I achieved my desired output the help of @Anbu & also based on the answer of @A.Jam.. 
Here is my correct code..

```
let img = UIImageView(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "defaultPhoto"))
        img.image = img.image?.resizeImageWith(newSize: CGSize(width: 25, height: 25))

        btnMyProfile.setImage(img.image, for: .normal)
        btnMyProfile.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        //btnMyProfile.imageView?.setRadius()
        btnMyProfile.imageView?.layer.cornerRadius = (btnMyProfile.imageView?.frame.width)! / 2
        btnMyProfile.imageView?.layer.borderColor = customeMainBlueColor.cgColor
        btnMyProfile.imageView?.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        btnMyProfile.imageView?.layer.masksToBounds = true

//someFile.swift
extension UIImage{
//https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42545955/scale-image-to-smaller-size-in-swift3
    func resizeImageWith(newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {

        let horizontalRatio = newSize.width / size.width
        let verticalRatio = newSize.height / size.height

        let ratio = max(horizontalRatio, verticalRatio)
        let newSize = CGSize(width: size.width * ratio, height: size.height * ratio)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, true, 0)
        draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: newSize))
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return newImage!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add image to button's background and make sure the size of button is proportional like 20*20, 30*30 etc, and set same corner radius as you already set.

Answer (score -1):

This answer is too late but maybe it helps someone

Simply go to storyboard, select your Image View, select Attributes Inspector then change Content Mode from Aspect Fit to Aspect Fill